# Wifi issues with Mediatek MT7921K (RZ608)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kde, mediatek

I'm currently using Kubuntu and having constant issues with wifi. I am able to get about 15 minutes of connection before it randomly disconnects stating "wlp6s0 The wifi network could not be found." and then reconnecting within a few minutes, and then does it all over again.

I have a Win10 dual boot that does not encounter this issue.

sudo lshw -C network

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz

configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.2.0-33-generic firmware=____010000-20230302150956 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I have read quite a bit about this, but it seems that the correct driver is being used and I am also on a kernel which has already received the patch for this card (6.2) so I'm at a loss for now.

Thanks for reading.

output of iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MOTOROLA-8232C"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 38:94:ED:97:2D:43   
          Bit Rate=115.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Output of `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` at time of disconnection:

```
<warn>  [1696133300.9971] device (wlp6s0): link timed out.
<info>  [1696133300.9973] device (wlp6s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1696133300.9976] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
<warn>  [1696133300.9978] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MOTOROLA-8232C'
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for  `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`. Try turning `Power Management` OFF. Read `man ip ip-dev ip-link` to see how.

Comment: @walinator I did not see any mention of power management in the ip manual but was able to turn it off by editing `default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`. I will use it for a while and report back with what happens. Thank you.

Comment: @walinator Still getting disconnected, I edited my post to show the output of `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` at the time of disconnection.